# Get the selected row of a GridView that's nested in a Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a dropdown in my Repeater that is populated based on which row is selected inside a Gridview that is nested within the Repeater.

I need the dropdown to refresh based on what row is selected in the GridView.

Usually I could get the currently selected row like this:

```
Protected Sub GvRevisionInfo2_OnSelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim country As String = TryCast(GridView1.SelectedRow.FindControl("lblCountry"), Label).Text
End Sub
```

But I don't know the ID of the GridView because it's generated dynamically inside the Repeater. Sometimes there's 2 GridViews other times there is 20.

So how do I get the values from the currently selected row inside a dynamically generated GridView in the codebehind?

Comment: Try following : Protected Sub GvRevisionInfo2_OnSelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim dgvRow As DataGridViewRow = CType(sender, DataGridViewRow)
        Dim country As String = dgvRow.Cells("lblCountry").Value
    End Sub

Comment: thanks. trying that but DataGridViewRow is not defined. I have imports System, isn't DataGridViewRow within win forms which is in system?

Comment: Do you have GridViewRowPresenter instead of a DataGridViewRow?

Answer (score 2):

You can cast the `sender` back to a GridView and use that.

```
Protected Sub GvRevisionInfo2_OnSelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim gridView As GridView = CType(sender,GridView)
    Dim label As Label = CType(gridView.SelectedRow.FindControl("lblCountry"),Label)
    Dim country As String = label.Text
End Sub
```